# file_get_contents failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Tags: php

I am Getting following error "Warning: file_get_contents failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request " while hitting "http://Google.com"

```
<?php
    $content = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
    if (strpos($http_response_header[0], "200")) { 
     echo "SUCCESS";
   } 
   else { 
          echo "FAILED";
        }?>
```

because of this problem i am not able to parse the URL .I am using WAMP(Apache Version-2.2.22,PHP version 5.4.3).

Steps taken :- 1.allow_url_fopen Enabled in php.ini 2.Tried Encoding the URL 3.Even Used Curl php function getting same problem. 4.Allowed Firewall on

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `file_get_contents` function cannot get content from a https stream, so you got the

> Warning: file_get_contents failed to open stream

Notice that although the url you pass to file_get_contents in http, it will eventually redirect to a https one (you can try in a browser)

If you want to get content from https, using [cUrl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead.

Regards,

Comment: This is not true. You can get file_get_contents to stream data from https, provided you provide the correct ssl context.

Comment: Not true and misleading. I have used file_get_contents many times with https